# Is it possible to make a Composable as an AccessibilityService Overlay?

Tags: android, kotlin, overlay, accessibilityservice, jetpack

Composables requires application lifecycle to work properly. But in the case of AccessibilityService the lifecycle is a bit different.

I was able to make a composable as an overlay using the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. But wasn't able to make it work using the accessibility service.